# I want to use pagination in a page after a custom post type has appeared 5 times. I cannot let the pagination kick in

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I can;t get pagination working. I have made a custom post type crop_2014 and a page which selects the ctp. I wan't to show the next five posts on teh next page but it doesn't work.

This is the code i use:

```
    <div class="col-md-7">

    <?php
         if (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
         <p><?php the_content()?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>



        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
        $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'crop_2014',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby'=> 'title',
        'order'=> 'ASC',
        'paged'=> $paged
        ) ); ?>

                <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $num = wp_count_posts(); ?>
                <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="show-case">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="show-prod">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('showpro'); ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="show-prod-rest">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                <p><strong><?php the_field('gender');?></strong></p>
                <p><strong><?php the_field('far');?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php the_field('mor');?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php the_field('morfar');?></strong></p>
                <p><strong><?php the_field('status');?></strong></p>
                </div>
                </div>          
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>












    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="choice-yearling-blok">
    </div>
        <div class="choice-yearling-blok-2">
                <div class="choice-yearling-blok-2-top">
                <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'choice', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) ); ?>
                <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>Hier komt de paginering</p>
    <?php  get_template_part('includes/pagination'); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template in 'includes/pagination' probably uses the WordPress functions next_posts_link and previous_posts_link. These feed off of the standard WordPress loop. However, you are using a custom loop to get your posts.

One approach is to write your own functions to create links to the next/previous group.

Perhaps easier is to modify the default loop instead of creating your own custom loop. For example:

```
query_posts( array(
   'post_type' => 'crop_2014',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby'=> 'title',
    'order'=> 'ASC',
    'paged'=> $paged
));
if (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...
```